# How to Retrieve Daily Plays/views for a Month Using Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Problem:

Need to obtain the total number of Plays/views for a specific video on a daily basis for a month-long period.
Current video-id/video_insights/ endpoint only provides overall totals.
Goal:

Access daily Plays/views  for a given video over a 30-day timeframe.
Request for Assistance:

Seeking guidance on how to achieve this using Graph API Explorer.
Thank you in advance for your help!